# htaccess 301 redirect of single URL to new path fails

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have a couple of structurally unrelated links that I need to forward. Since they are different I wont be able to use a common pattern but have to forward each manually. They look something like this:

```
shop/single/?products[backPID]=127&tt_products[sword]=yoo&
```

tt_products[product]=822&cHash=8758b181408d3380euios61

I tried forwarding with something like this but it doesnt work while other "normal" links work just fine...

```
Redirect permanent /shop/single/?products[backPID]=127&tt_products[sword]=yoo&tt_products[product]=822&cHash=8758b181408d3380euios61 http://www.new-url.de/shop/
```

Also tried but unfortunately not working:

```
RewriteRule ^shop/single/?products[backPID]=127&tt_products[sword]=yoo&tt_products[product]=822&cHash=8758b181408d3380euios61 http://www.new-url.de/shop/ [QSA,R=301]
```

Any clues to why this might be? Do I have to do something with the parameters before theys can be forwarded?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a RewriteCond to match against the full uri

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /shop/single/\?products\[backPID\]=127&tt_products\[sword\]=yoo&tt_products\[product\]=822&cHash=8758b181408d3380euios61 [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ http://www.new-url.de/shop/? [R,L]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I think thats what I did before and I tried again with your exacct code but to no avail :( Any ideas what else might be the cause?

`RewriteCond /shop/singel/\?tt_products\[backPID\]=227&tt_products\[sword\]=leo&tt_products\[product\]=822&cHash=88758b181408d305f59f200d124b3261 [NC]`
`RewriteRule ^ http://www.new-shop.de/? [R,L]`

Comment: what url are you going to ? please post the URI.